# Return Integer value from SSIS execute SQL Task

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, parameter-passing

I am using SQL Server 2005 Business Intelligence Studio and struggling with returning an integer value from a very simple execute SQL Task. 
For a very simple test, I wrote the SQL Statement as:

```
Select 35 As 'TotalRecords'
```

Then, I specified ResultSet as

```
ResultName = TotalRecords and
VariableName = User::TotalRecords
```

When I execute this, the statement is executed but the variable doesn't have the updated value. However, it has the default value that I specified while variable definition.

The return of a date variable works, but integer variable isn't working. The type of `User::TotalRecords` specified is Int32 in a package scope.

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 11):

The value for Result Name is incorrect. Try using an ordinal (position) based approach.

A basic set up for an OLE or ADO.NET Execute SQL Task

[image]

Here I have specified the ordinal of 0 for the zeroeth column in my resultset.

[image]

Here you can see the original variables and their values (-1, -2) as well as their run-time values of 35 for both.

[image]

Comment: Almost anything you do in integration services is going to have to be shown with screen shots. If your workplace blocks imgur you kind of out of luck. There really is no way to explain complex ssis steps with words alone.

Answer (score 0):

Once your package completes yuor variables go back to their default state. If you use a breakpoint or a msgbox, you'll see that during execution your variable does have the value.