# Execute SQL task works in developer and SSMS but errors out in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent, sql-agent-job

This code works in the SSIS editor, SSMS and running from the catalog.

Here is the code:

```
declare @maxDate as date

select @maxDate = cast(max([Date]) as date)  
from [dbo].[sometable]
--print   @maxDate

declare @currDate as date
select @currDate = cast(getdate() as date) ;
--print  @currDate

if  @maxDate  <> @currDate  
BEGIN
    THROW 55000, 'Staging has not run for today!',1 ;
END
```

Error is:

[image]

Comment: you will need to post entire error message as text

Comment: Are you sure this error is thrown by this Sql task??!! Please give us the original code

Comment: If you would have added the date to the error message you're throwing, you would know what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

When the query is run in SSMS the result will look something like the one shown in Figure1 below.

[image: Figure1]

Figure 1 - Results in SSMS running original query

There is something being returned to the messages tab.

If you use an Execute SQL task in SSIS (the example here is from Visual Studio 2015).  When you select that task you can select to return a results set, which can be a single or full results set.  See figure 2 for where those options are set.

[image]

Figure 2 - shows where select which type of results set to return.

Based on the error message the Execute SQL task is expecting results set to be returned.  The results set is the data returned in the results tab when the query is run in SSMS.  See Figure 3 for an example of a one row, one field results set.

[image]

Figure 3 - Amended query returning a single row result set

Once the task has been configured to return a results set you can work with the dataset.  For example, assign the single value to an SSIS variable and take actions based on that value.  This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116050001/http://sqlis.com/sqlis/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx) gives some ideas of what can be done, or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565964/return-integer-value-from-ssis-execute-sql-task).